# How to make HTTP Analyzer/Fiddler inspect a running Java console

Tags: java, http, console, fiddler, inspection

Is there any way to Inspect Java HTTP traffic through HTTP Analyzer/Fiddler without modifying the source java code to use SOCKS proxy?

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureJavaApp Failing that WireShark/MS Network Monitor will capture everything.

Comment: Yep failing. Wireshark will do but that's like looking for a needle in a haystack :)

Comment: See if [this](http://codeketchup.blogspot.in/2014/03/how-to-use-eclipse-with-fiddler-step-by.html) helps. If you're calls are using https, you've to all the steps in the blog, if not basic http tracing will be easy to configure

Answer (score 0):

I've NEVER had a problem getting Java traffic capture by either setting the JVM parameters on the command line, or in the Java system control panel.

Having said that, if you capture the traffic in Wireshark, you can save it to a `pcapng` file and then `File` > `Import Packet Capture` the traffic into Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks for the Wireshark import into Fiddler tip. Better something than nothing.